# Frama-c Pre-processing Error

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I want to slice a c code but when I write the commands I get some errors which are down.

```
*******[15:18, 26.10.2017] Recep: [kernel] Parsing .opam/system/share/frama-c/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)

[kernel] user error: source file "helloworld.c" does not exist

[kernel] user error: stopping on file "helloworld.c" that has errors. Add 

'-kernel-msg-key pp'

                     for preprocessing command.

[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.*******
```

Comment: No one can't help you with an error.Add your code please.

Comment: When I write the command     frama-c helloworld.c    I am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "source file "helloworld.c" does not exist" indicates, that there is no such file, so make sure that it exists, and can be found by Frama-C, i.e., it is in your working (current) directory.